# "Image as plane" won't disappear

Tags: materials, image, grease-pencil

I added an image as plane as a background behind my grease pencil animation. Then, fiddled with it on the Shader Editor so I could change its opacity (to fade from one image to the next).

This is the background image:
[image]

The problem is that a ghost of that image is in every scene. Even when I delete the entire "image as plane" object, the ghost doesn't disappear. Here are two examples of previous scenes that are affected:
[image]

[image]

And below is a ss of my material properties tab. If there are more ss I need to add to help make sense of this, pls let me know.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select every previous "image plane as background" and uncheck *Show backface* in *Materials Properties* tab.